# Is it possible to determine which level/key of a nested dict that contained None, causing 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, python-3.7

The users of my framework (who may or may not be well versed in Python) write code that navigates a dict (that originally came from a json response from some API).

Sometimes they make a mistake, or sometimes the API returns data with some value missing, and they get the dreaded `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

How can I make it clear at what level the error occured? (what key returned None)

```
def user_code(some_dict):
    # I can't modify this code, it is written by the user
    something = some_dict["a"]["b"]["c"]

# I don't control the contents of this.
data_from_api = '{"a": {"b": None}}'

# framework code, I control this
try:
    user_code(json.loads(data_from_api))
except TypeError as e:
    # I'd like to print an error message containing "a","b" here
```

I can overload/alter the dict implementation if necessary, but I don't want to do source code inspection.

There may already be answers to this question (or maybe it is impossible), but it is terribly hard to find among all the basic *Why am I getting 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable?* questions. My apologies if this is a duplicate.

Edit: @2e0byo's answer is the most correct to my original question, but I did find [autoviv](https://gitlab.com/tysonholub/python-autoviv) to provice a nice solution to my "real" underlying issue (allowing users to easily navigate a dict that sometimes doesnt have all the expected data), so I chose that approach instead. The only real down side with it is if someone relies on `some_dict["a"]["b"]["c"]` to throw an exception. My solution is something like this:

```
def user_code(some_dict):
    # this doesnt crash anymore, and instead sets something to None
    something = some_dict["a"]["b"]["c"]

# I don't control the contents of this.
data_from_api = '{"a": {"b": None}}'

# framework code, I control this
user_code(autoviv.loads(data_from_api))
```

Comment: `for k in ('a', 'b', 'c'): d = d[k]`… That gives you more control of each step and more possibilities to introspect…?

Comment: Reduce the amount of chained subscripts you use. Instead of `something = d["a"]["b"]["c"]` use `a = d["a"]; b = a["b"]; something = b["c"]` Bonus points if the names a and b actually mean something.

Comment: I dont want to change user code, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I rephrased the question, as it really isnt *my* API, it could be *any* API

Comment: Yield a custom class, not a dict, with overrided getter?

Comment: I thought about that, but how would the custom class know whether None is a problem or an entirely appropriate thing to return? None is completely fine it is the last step in the the dict traversal...

Comment: Same as you did above: catch a `TypeError`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Did you read the whole question? Oh, and to be specific, the TypeError doesnt contain any information about what the preceeding dict key (b) was (or even the last one, c) as far as I can see.

Comment: No, but if you implement it yourself, you have all the information you need. I would post an answer if I understood your question better

Comment: what about just modifying the message?  so it raises 'NoneType is not subscriptable.  Are you sure your code should be passing None' or something like that. Then when they google the custom error message they'll get to your docs. There will be false positives (real Nones) but with less noise you can deal with those in the docs.

Comment: Also am I right in thinking that your 'user code goes here' means that you do `yield d`?  If so would you update the q to show that, or something like `user_code(d)`.  The point being that you have to chuck up the *whole* object, right?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Are you suggesting I override the behaviour of the None returned by the dict? I guess I *could* do that, but it would be kind of weird and I'd have to iterate the whole dict replacing None:s with my SpecialNone:s, or monkey patching the None class...

Comment: @Cyberwiz I was actually going to suggest that.  I'll post an answer as to how I would do it.

Comment: @2e0byo Rewriting the error message might make it easier to understand for some people, but also more unusual for people familiar with the regular error message (and harder to google :)

Comment: @2e0byo your thinking is correct, there is really a yield there. I'll make the effort to update the question if we find a good answer.

Comment: Updated. Didnt actually use yield, because I'm lazy.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to look at the problem from a different point of view: If it's common to access deeply nested json data, why not supply an object that makes this more convenient (e.g. `data["a", "b", "c"]`)? This way, it would be easy to handle the error and your users get an easier method to access the data. There are also already libraries for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach to this problem: make your code return a custom `Result()` object wrapping each object.  (This approach could be generalised to a monad approach with `.left()` and `.right()`, but I didn't go there as I don't see that pattern very often (in my admittedly small experience!).)

### Example Code

Firstly the custom `Result()` object:

```py
class Result:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        try:
            return self._val[k]
        except KeyError:
            raise Exception("No such key")
        except TypeError:
            raise Exception(
                "Result is None.  This probably indicates an error in your code."
            )

    def __getattr__(self, a):
        try:
            return self._val.a
        except AttributeError:
            if self._val is None:
                raise Exception(
                    "Result is None.  This probably indicates an error in your code."
                )
            else:
                raise Exception(
                    f"No such attribute for value of type {type(self._val)}, valid attributes are {dir(self._val)}"
                )

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val
```

Of course, there's a lot of room for improvement here (e.g. `__repr__()` and you might want to modify the error messages).

In action:

```py
def to_result(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, dict):
        return Result({k: to_result(v) for k, v in thing.items()})
    else:
        return Result(thing)

d = {"a": {"b": None}}
r_dd = to_result(d)
r_dd["a"] # Returns a Result object
r_dd["a"]["b"] # Returns a Result object
r_dd["a"]["c"] # Raises a helpful error
r_dd["a"]["b"]["c"] # Raises a helpful error
r_dd["a"]["b"].val # None
r_dd["a"]["b"].nosuchattr # Raises a helpful error
```

### Reasoning

If I'm going to serve up a custom object I want my users to *know* it's a custom object.  So we have a wrapper class, and we tell users that the paradim is 'get at the object, and then use .val to get the result'. Handling the wrong .val is *their* code's problem (so if `.val` is None, they have to handle that).  But handling a problem in the data structure is sort of our problem, so we hand them a custom class with helpful messages rather than anything else.

### Getting the level of the nested error

As currently implemented it's easy to get one above in the error msg (for dict lookups).  If you want to get more than that you need to keep a reference up the hierarchy in the Result---which might be better written with Result as something other than just a wrapper.

I'm not sure if this is the kind of solution you were looking for, but it might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! This is probably as good as it gets. However, I'm not sure having to teach my users to use a custom way to access the data (specifically the extra *.val* to get the actual data) outweights the benefits. 

I'll hold off a while on accepting the answer in case someone comes along with a magical solution that is more transparent.